# Cannot append teradata volatile table using RODBC

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc

Alright folks,

I am trying to append a volatile table on a teradata server using RODBC. The code I have written is as follows:

```
create_query = paste(
  'CREATE VOLATILE TABLE',
  volatile_name,
  '(',  dl_uid, ' VARCHAR(', char_width, '))',
  'UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(', dl_uid, ')',
  "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;"
)

RODBC::sqlQuery(
  channel,
  query = create_query
)

RODBC::sqlSave(
  channel,
  dat = df2,
  tablename = volatile_name,
  rownames = FALSE,
  append = TRUE
)
```

This is the error message I get:

> Error in RODBC::sqlSave(channel = edv, dat = df2, tablename =
>   volatile_name,  :    42S01 -3803 [Teradata][ODBC Teradata
>   Driver][Teradata Database] Table 'edvR_4425' already exists.  [RODBC]
>   ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE "edvR_4425"  ("id_num"
>   varchar(255))'

I find this a bit strange as I chose the argument `append = TRUE` so that it would know to append a pre-existing table. I have tried this code with a permanent table and it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont know how rodbc works, but *append=TRUE* might simply check the system tables/views if the table already exists and a Volatile Table can't be found in dbc. See if QueryLog is enabled and check the submitted SQL

Comment: Does it behave any differently with a permanent table?

Comment: Teradata also offers a [Teradata SQL Driver for R](https://github.com/Teradata/r-driver) which may be easier to use than RODBC, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Fred Thanks I will check that out